# How do I package a fyne app? file does not exist error

Tags: go, build, path, environment-variables, fyne

The error message is `error building application: exec: "C:\\Program Files\\Go\\bin": file does not exist`, and I got it by running `fyne install` (or `fyne serve` or `fyne package`).

I suspect that it has something to do with my GOPATH, but not sure what.

### Some environment variables:

GOPATH is a user variable : `C:\Users\ethan\go\bin`

go is a system variable:  `C:\Program Files\Go\bin`

Both of those are also in the Path system variable, as well as the directory of the `run.go` file in the working directory and its parent.

### C:\Program Files\Go\bin

**Contains files:**

go.exe

gofmt.exe

### C:\Users\ethan\go\bin

**Contains files:**

fyne.exe

gopls.exe

fyne-cross.exe

staticcheck.exe

dlv.exe

yaegi.exe

gopls.exe--

Comment: What do you mean by "go is a system variable"? There is no environment variable named `$GO` on Windows (well, maybe there is on your system because you've created it, but it won't be used by anything).

Comment: @JoryGeerts Yes, there is a system variable named "go". Are you saying that I should delete it?

Comment: > Yes, there is a system variable named "go"... Wondering if that overwrites / shadows the `go` executable. It looks like it from the error: "error building application: exec: "C:\\Program Files\\Go\\bin": file does not exist". Looks like it tries to execute the bin folder...

Comment: Yes Ethan, like @TehSphinX says, it could very well be the cause of your problems, so I'd delete it and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Ok, looks like that worked. If you list your response as an answer, I'll accept and close.